# Matlab TabPanel usage

Tags: user-interface, matlab, tabpanel, handles

I am trying to use the application [TabPanel Constructor v2.8](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6996-tabpanel-constructor-v2-8-2010). I have followed the instructions given with it. In the openingfcn of my gui I need to select one of the tabs. For it, I should use the tabselectionfcn which is adjunct with the mentioned application. This function has the following signature:

```
TABSELECTIONFCN(<hFig>,<TabTag>,<tabnumber>)
%     <hFig>      the handle(!) of the Figure (which contains the tabpanel)
%                 and not the name of the figure file.
%     <TabTag>    the Tag name of the tabpanel
%     <tabnumber> The number of the tabpanel or the tab string
```

When I research for the variable handles of my gui to find  handles of the tabpanels, I do not see them. If I open the .fig file of my gui they do not appear, so I do not know what to do to overcome this problem.

P.D. I sent an email to the author of this application but I did not get answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need tabpanel handle, but figure handle.

The handle for figure created by GUIDE is hidde by default. Its visibility is controlled by [figure property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure_props.html#HandleVisibility) `HandleVisibility`, which is set to `callback` for GUI to protect them from command line user. The handle is visible from inside the callback function, like

```
yourgui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
```

where `hObject` is the handle you need. You can find all callback functions in the m-file associated with the fig-file.

You can also get the handle from outside the GUI opening the FIG file as

```
fh = openfig('yourgui.fig');
```

Alternatively you can use [FINDALL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/findall.html) to find an object (including hidden) by its properties:

```
fh = findall(0,'type','figure'); %# all open figures including GUIs
fh = findall(0,'name','yourgui'); %# find by name
```

Then you can control a tab with TABSELECTIONFCN:

```
tabselectionfcn(fh,'myTab') %# get the tab status
tabselectionfcn(fh,'myTab',2) %# activate the 2nd tab
tabselectionfcn(fh,'myTab',1,'off') %# disable the 1nd tab (if not active)
```

The tabpanel Tag name is the `Tag` property of the static text object you used as a placeholder while creating the tabpanel. You can find it if you open your GUI in GUIDE and inspect the tabpanel properties with Property Inspector. That will look like `TBP_myTab`.

By the way, if you do need tabpanels handle you can get them also with FINDALL:

```
htab = findall(fh,'tag','TBP_myTab');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have just realized what were my errors.

Comment: Hi back. I think I would need your help with my question Matlab GUIDE ResizeFcn Callback.